# Increase cursor/caret width?

Tags: notepad++

In Windows, I set my caret to be larger for vision reasons.  In my browser, notepad++, and many other programs, it doesn't inherit this preference.  Is it possible (if only by altering source code) to increase the caret size in NPP and/or other programs written in C++?

Comment: Also available in SublimeText3 under `Preferences -> Settings -> "caret_extra_width": 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about any generic way to do this for applications that do not respect the Windows settings. However:

**Notepad++** allows changing the caret width. The choices are 0, 1, 2, and 3 pixels, and "block". 0 pixels makes the caret invisible. In the menu bar, choose "Settings", then "Preferences", and finally "Editing".

[image]

In **Firefox**, you can change it thus:

type `about:config` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Click that you understand the warning!
Right-click the page

New > Integer
Name: `ui.caretWidth`
Value: *N*

(Value *N* is a number, the desired caret width in pixels)

New > Integer
Name: `ui.caretBlinkTime`
Value: *N*

(Value *N* is the number of milliseconds. 250 ms would be four blinks each second; normal is around 500 ms I think.)

Comment: amazing!~ thank you for this great answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!